# Why did these people die in Serenity?

Tags: movie, serenity

In the film [*Serenity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_(film)) several fan-favourite characters die:

> [Hoban Wash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoban_Washburne#Hoban_Washburne) and [Shepherd Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derrial_Book). 
>  In particular, I felt that Wash's death seemed especially pointless - not a heroic end but just *dead* without even a closing speech, unlike Shepherd who at least got to make a few wisecracks.

**What is the out of universe reason for this?**

Was it just to heighten the tension, since almost everyone was injured at the end and could have died as well? Or did [Joss Whedon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joss_Whedon) want to refresh the crew in any future series?

Comment: Have you ever seen anything else Whedon created?  He almost always kills off major characters.  It's part of his writing style.

Comment: @BBlake: I haven't no, so thanks for the info.

Comment: I'm puzzled why this is attracting downvotes, so comments are welcome.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

About Wash specifically, Whedon himself said:

> Dramatically, the more I worked on [the screenplay], the more it
>   became clear that in order to make people feel that this was real, a
>   certain shocking thing is going to have to happen.

Cited in [this article](http://io9.com/5905802/why-does-joss-whedon-always-kill-the-characters-we-love) which is entirely about Whedon's tendencies to do such things in many of his series, and the reasons behind it. I'm with him - heroic deaths are by now a ridiculously worn-out trope.

Note that he's *also* said that he would [not have killed off Wash](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Hoban_Washburne) if the series had not been cancelled, so kinda the opposite of your speculation: he used the opportunity of not having to "conserve" characters to give the story more impact.

This shows a fundamental weakness of the series format: you want to continue using characters, so you can't have them die even if it would make for a better story. When writers want to have their cake and eat it too here, it leads to [comic book death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death).

Comment: Quiet a few TV show do kill major characters: Babylon 5 for example.  But I agree with you that they rarely kill protagonists.

Comment: Moral of the story: Joss Whedon kills the things you love.  Usually with a chest wound.

Comment: @Sardathrion: Are you referring to a specific death in Season 4?  If so, I'd say its for the same reasons.
@ AdeleC: Or heartbreak (Dr. Horrible).

Comment: @Corwin01: Season 2, Season 3, and Seasons 4 all have main characters deaths.  Yeah sure, you can argue who is a main character and who is not...

Comment: As an attempt around this weakness of the series format, "Heros" was planned having a continually rotating ensemble cast with a really high body count among "main" characters.  The show became quite popular very quickly (along with the characters), and the cast rotation was significantly reduced.  As another attempt, "American Horror Story" has a new setting every season, in which all actors play new characters.  This frees up the writers to kill off main characters while still keeping actors involved in the series.

Comment: Whedon reverses Wash's death in the comics, well, sort of.